# Verb to be and measurement and dimensions

Tags: verbs

Any chances of using the verb to be to refer to weight; I mean, as a synonym for "weigh" eg: The baby was 5 pounds. If it is ok please let me know how frequently natives use it.

Comment: I've never heard anyone say: "The baby was X pounds", meaning that's what the baby weighed. The verb "to be" might be used in a conversation such as: "I've just weighed the baby". "OH REALLY!" "Yes, she's now 5 pounds".

Comment: @RonaldSole - Really?  "The baby was five pounds, ten ounces" seems like a perfectly normal thing to say to me.  I'm not sure how your example is any different other than you said "she" instead of "the baby".

Comment: @stangdon -The point is that the weight of the baby is already under discussion and it's clear that weight is what one's talking about. While I've not had a lot to do with babies, I've never heard a statement out of the blue telling me what the baby WAS. "The baby was five pounds," sounds a bit like the market price.

Comment: @RonaldSole not in the US where "pound" is never a price

Comment: @RonaldSole - I added a number of examples showing this in live usage.  It may be a UK/US difference, where "pound" is less ambiguous in the US and so the phrasing is more likely.

Comment: I sorry but this is not a UK/US difference. When I read that, I wonder what people's experience of speech actually is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, people use this phrasing all the time.  If you say that something is X pounds, particularly if you're talking about a baby, it's usually pretty clear that you're talking about weight, and you don't have to say it explicitly.  Examples from actual usage:

> [On the last day of May the ultrasound showed that the baby was six pounds, two ounces.](https://books.google.com/books?id=U2_eAb5NF00C&pg=PA212&dq=%22the%20baby%20was%20*%20pounds%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQvoWD6qDPAhXKpYMKHfIRDwAQ6AEIQjAG#v=onepage&q=%22the%20baby%20was%20*%20pounds%22&f=false)
>
> [I went for my ultrasound today and they estimated that the baby was 5 pounds](http://www.whattoexpect.com/forums/may-2015-babies/topic/est-31-weeks-and-baby-is-5-pounds-wrong-due-date.html)
>
> [The baby was 10 pounds](http://time.com/3661318/woman-didnt-know-she-was-pregnant/)

Comment: You repeated what I said and not as well. Did you even bother to read my answer??

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if you are discussing weight, you use the verb to weigh. However, if it's everyday speech, and the people having the conversation have **already expressed the idea of weight**, you can say to be:

Mary: "My baby weighs 25 pounds now".

Sarah: "Really? Mine **is** [an alternative to using weighs] only 22, last time I checked".

Another example:

Mary: "What your baby's **weight**, Sarah?".

Sarah: "It'**s** 22 pounds, as of this morning".

A weight IS some amount.
A thing weighs some amount.
A thing IS some amount if it is already established that weight is being discussed.